# How to GET HTML dynamically created values with SAS's PROC HTTP

Tags: http, dom, get, sas, proc

I'm trying to use a PROC HTTP to get the constant changing's value of something (For example, the price of the BitCoin in this web: https://www.coindesk.com/price/)

If we used the  F12 to open the inspector and look for the big price's label element we could find:

```
<div id="cdbpidata">
  <span class="wpsr_floatbts_anchor" data-offset="31" style="float: left;"></span>
  <div class="latest">
    <span class="data"><span class="symbol">$</span>8,165.12</span>
    <span class="percent data-up">0.02%</span>
  </div>
   .
   .
   .
</div>
```

I want to get that '8,165.12' and put it on a DataSet. Then I used this:

```
proc http
   url='https://www.coindesk.com/price/'
   method='GET'
   out=resp;
run;
```

And it works! But not good enough. I receive this in my xml:

```
<div id="cdbpidata">
  <span class="wpsr_floatbts_anchor" data-offset="31" style="float: left;"></span>
  <div class="latest">
     <span class="data">–</span>
     <span class="percent"></span>
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
</div>
```

No big number for me, so bad. Obviously it's because the price is printed in the DOM with a javascript function, but I don't know how to get it then!
Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dug a little more into the developer tools network tab you would see that the page made a json data request from a coindesk api.  You could perform the same query and not need to scrape the html page.

You should review coindesk policies before hitting the api's.  You might need to get a user key or there might be other terms limiting data pulls.

```
filename outjson 'c:\temp\prices.json';

proc http
   url='https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/allcurrencies.json?showex=1&calc=1'
   method='GET'
   out=outjson
;
run;
```

SAS has a `json` library engine that works similar to the `xml` library engine.

```
libname price json 'c:\temp\prices.json';

data price_usd;
  set price.bpi_usd;
run;

proc print data=price_usd;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: very nice!  Might also want to use a Bitcoin format :-)  https://www.rawsas.com/2018/03/bitcoin-sas-format/

Comment: Excelent! But what happens with https://www.goldmoney.com/ for example, that does not have an API?

Comment: Are you sure ? Did you look for one ? Use developer tools to examine the network activity for their page research/live-prices-and-charts and look for items with json content, such as `dataByTimeFrame`